# source filtering not working in elasticsearch 1.0.0.beta

Tags: elasticsearch

according to the docs, it is possible to do source filtering on the returned document beginning with elasticseach 1.0.0beta

I tried all the examples from the url below, but the source is always completely returned.
Also, when sending _source:false, the whole document is still returned as well.

Is this a known issue?

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-request-source-filtering.html

Comment: This works for me.  Please add details of the actual curl commands that you are running.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. Needed to use POST instead of PUT